# Como pasar un List<Model> de una "View" a una "Action" de un "Controller"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en Net Core 5 MVC.

Tengo una vista donde cargo un Selectlist y cargo las existencias del almacen, la idea es que al dar clic en "Generar Salida" me cargue una vista con los datos requeridos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago clic en "Generar Salida" entra perfectamente bien el "Action" y los primeros dos parametros llegan bien, pero el tercero que es el modelo llega nulo.

Este es la vista:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebProcesoTela.Models.VAlmacenExistenciasModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<h5>Inventario Disponible</h5>
<div class="container container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" style="width: 100%">
        <thead class="tableHead-md">
            <tr>
                <!-- Oculto @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AlmacenId) -->
                <!-- Oculto @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticuloId) -->
                <th class="col-md-2">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AlmacenShort)</th>
                <th class="col-md-5">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticuloName)</th>
                <th class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TipoMovimiento)</th>
                <th class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Existencias)</th>
                <th class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CostoExistencias)</th>
                <th class="col-md-3">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Lote)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tableBody-md">
            @{
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.AlmacenId, new {@class="form-group"})
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ArticuloId, new {@class="form-group"})
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ArticuloCatId, new {@class="form-group"})
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AlmacenShort)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArticuloName)</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TipoMovimiento)</td>
                        <td class="text-end">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Existencias)</td>
                        <td class="text-end">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CostoExistencias)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lote)</td>
                    </tr>
                }}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Barra de Botones Datails Modal <Regresar> -->
    <partial name="/Views/Shared/Controls/_BtnsDetailsModal.cshtml"/>
    <a id="btnSalidaAlm" class="btnSalidaAlm btn btn-primary" href="/DoctosAlmMaster/CreateDoctoByAlmacen?id=@Model.ElementAt(0).AlmacenId &almacen=@Model.ElementAt(0).AlmacenShort &stock=@Model.AsEnumerable().ToList()"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-to-bracket"></i> Generar Salida</a>
</div>
```

Aqui es donde mando los parametros (id, almacen, stock):

```
<a id="btnSalidaAlm" class="btnSalidaAlm btn btn-primary" href="/DoctosAlmMaster/CreateDoctoByAlmacen?id=@Model.ElementAt(0).AlmacenId &almacen=@Model.ElementAt(0).AlmacenShort &stock=@Model.AsEnumerable().ToList()"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-to-bracket"></i> Generar Salida</a>
```

Y este es el "Action" del controlador

```
// GET: DoctosAlmMasterController/CreateDoctoByAlmacen
public IActionResult CreateDoctoByAlmacen(int id, string almacen, List<VAlmacenSaldosModel> stock)    
{
  //Aqui es donde id y almacen, llegan correctamente, pero stock llega nulo
  DoctosAlmMasterViewModel doctosAlmMasterViewModel = new();
  doctosAlmMasterViewModel.DoctosAlmDetail = new();

  // Aqui van otras cosas, pero no es relevante para la consulta
  return View(doctosAlmMasterViewModel);
}
```

No tengo idea que estoy haciendo mal (tengo poca experiencia en Net Core).
¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar con este problema?, de antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías tener la lista en un formulario y al dar click en el botón `Generar Salida` se enviarían todos los elementos. Podrías mandar los mismos parámetros con los que generaste la lista, los consultas de nuevo y tienes a todos los elementos nuevamente. Workshop recomendado: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Comment: @fredyfx, te agradezco mucho los comentarios, la vista esta en un formulario (como recomiendas), la vista que pongo aqui y que genera la tabla es una vista parcial que inserto en el formulario "padre", aun asi el modelo pasa null,
Estuve checando el video (es muy largo 4 hrs) y no encontre algo similar a lo que estoy haciendo, pero gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Muy largo dices... Te informo que ese es un resumen de un curso de 27 horas y quizás un poco más de lo que en su tiempo fue la Microsoft Virtual Academy. De nada.

Comment: @fredyfx me da la impresión que te ofendiste por el comentario sobre el video, si es así, me disculpo aunque no fue mi intención ofender a nadie.
De cualquier forma nuevamente te agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Vale, descuida, no pasa nada. Saludos.